# DataGridView From the Web

Tags: datagridview, mdf

Basically, I now have my .mdf file for my DataGridView. The contents that the dataGridView loads is within that file. However, if I deploy this software onto another computer, it no longer works despite changing the file location. So, I need to be able to put this data online so it can be used inside the application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these things
1. Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections
•Start > All Programs > SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Surface Area Configuration
•Click on Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections
•Select the instance that is having a problem > Database Engine > Remote Connections
•Enable local and remote connections
•Restart instance

1. Check the SQL Server service account
   •If you are not using a domain account as a service account (for example if you are using NETWORK SERVICE), you may want to switch this first before proceeding

3.If you are using a named SQL Server instance, make sure you are using that instance name in your connection strings in your ASweb P.NET application
•Usually the format needed to specify the database server is machinename\instancename
•Check your connection string as well

Comment: Parth, thanks for your assistance so far. However, I'm trying to get the MDF file onto an external computer without SQL server management studio and anything associated. All I need is the project and the MDF file deployed on their computer. However, when I run the project, it isn't able to load the MDF file.

Comment: Unless I could upload the file somewhere and would be readable for **free**.

Answer (score 0):

Then your .mdf save into your project folder (within any other folder). so during export .mdf file also save with your project folder(zip format).

Comment: The point is, is that the MDF file doesn't seem to be able to open when the file is placed in the exact location on a different computer. What happens is "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing connection to the SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: try this server name "(LocalDB)\v11.0".its works for me.@JamesHolland

Comment: I don't know what you do different. I am not using SQL Server Management Studio as I'm trying to deploy this at another location globally. So, I have a C# project. Basically, it has a dataGridView with the data source being the MDF file. Within the MDF file contains all the information required. However, could you explain where you type that in?